# JQuery Mobile `showPageLoadingMsg` not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

JQuery Mobile `showPageLoadingMsg` will not work in my application. The following code just produces the spinning wheel with no text:

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "please wait...");
```

I can get just the message by adding `true` as the last argument:

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "please wait...", true);
```

But **I cannot get the the wheel AND the message.** to appear at the same time

Do I need to have my own theme or... what am I missing?
Heres an example on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ashanova/VBavX/18/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the loadingMessageTextVisible property to true. Something like:

```
$.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true; // best to put this in mobile init
```

From the docs:
loadingMessageTextVisible boolean, default: false
Whether the text should be visible when a loading message is shown. The text is always visible for loading errors.

I think this property and the showPageLoading method is somewhat confusing and should be update or fix the showPageLoading appropriately.

Here is your updated example http://jsfiddle.net/VBavX/21/

Comment: Good call! I miss read the documentation thinking that the third argument to showPageLoadingMsg was setting loadingMessageTextVisible.  This has had me tearing my lack of hair out for ages

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's working properly.

If you take a look [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html) (the official documentation) you'll see that with "true" the wheel is hidden while showing the message.

Comment: Hi, I know that it works, I want to produce the wheel and the text at the same time.  I was just demonstrating that i could get the wheel or the text but not both